# Image in the update panel not getting updated

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I am working on Image Album like thing..Initially a image will be loaded in the IMG server control placed in the update panel..On clicking the Next button the next image has to load in the update panel, the code to which is given in the code behind class..though the button click is been called properly..the image is not changing on button click

This is my page

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
<div id="Container">
    <table border="0">
        <tr>
            <td align="left">
                <asp:ImageButton ID="cmdPrevious" runat="server" ImageUrl="/Images/GoPrevious.png"
                    Height="40" />
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                Album : Image (5/10)
            </td>
            <td align="right">
                <asp:ImageButton ID="cmdNext" runat="server" ImageUrl="/Images/GoNext.png" Height="40" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:Image ID="AlbumImage" runat="server" />
                    </ContentTemplate>
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="cmdNext" EventName="Click" />
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="cmdPrevious" EventName="Click" />
                    </Triggers>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Now this is the code behind..

```
Partial Class view
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Public fun As New functions
Public AlbumType, AlbumName, ImageUrl As String
Public ImgArray As String(,)

Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim Pid As Integer
    Dim TName As String
    AlbumType = Request.QueryString("AlbumType")
    AlbumName = Request.QueryString("AlbumName")
    ImageUrl = Request.QueryString("ImageUrl")
    Pid = fun.GetAlbumID(AlbumType & "/" & AlbumName & "/" & ImageUrl)
    TName = fun.GetTags4MefrmID(Pid)
    ImgArray = fun.getAlbumImages(TName, Pid)
    AlbumImage.ImageUrl  = "http://Sitename/Gallery/var/Albums/" & ImgArray(0, 2)


End Sub

Protected Sub cmdNext_Click(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs) Handles cmdNext.Click
    AlbumImage.ImageUrl  = "http://sitename/Gallery/var/Albums/" & ImgArray(1, 2)

End Sub
```

End Class

Please help me to find a way to change the image in the update panel on button click

Answer (score 0):

Move your page_load code in not Postback, you're rebinding to default image in page_load which will override your image set on event click.

Ex:

```
If(Not Page.IsPostBack) then
 AlbumImage.ImageUrl  = "http://Sitename/Gallery/var/Albums/" & ImgArray(0, 2)
END
```